# How can i implement Leaflet js in native android app

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android. I am making an android application which requires all features that **Leaflet js** provides on the web. Is there is such library or SDK available for android by which I can get all the features of  Leaflet js I am trying to make an android application which used to draw lines, draw shapes on layers without affecting original image.Also I don't  want to implement web view. I viewed many solutions like [Use leaflet in an android application to show online map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946316/use-leaflet-in-an-android-application-to-show-online-map) but neither helps. Thanks